# Blank screen after login in Kali Linux through remote desktop Connection in Windows 10

Tags: kali-linux, remote-desktop

I recently installed the Kali Linux app in Windows 10,(https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PKR34TNCV07) then followed the instructions on the website https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-in-the-windows-app-store/ . 
After then, I initiated remote desktop connection in Windows 10, and I logged in Kali Linux. 
All I am getting is a blank screen, and after some time the message below.

What can I do to run Kali Linux without this problem ?

[image: message window]

The Remote Desktop is set up correctly and the Kali Linux in the WSL is also installed properly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange. Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to best ask questions here. We want everyone to be welcome but there are rules everyone has to follow. So to get to your question. Could you please [edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/470265/edit) to include more context. Why are you trying to remote desktop into your Windows Subsystem for Linux? Are you remoting from a different computer? This is a Unix and Linux site, questions involving issues with Windows are kind of off topic here...

Comment: No, I'm remoting from the same computer.

Comment: Why are you trying to remote desktop onto your own computer? You can just launch Kali from the store page or the `.exe` it provides you with.

Comment: are you sure of VNC ? I think you'd be better using SSH

Comment: I am remoting from my own computer because the .exe executes Kali Linux terminal, and I want to run the xfce desktop with the Kali Linux. I just followed this video. https://vimeo.com/255052199

Comment: Is port 3350 the port that `xrdp` set up? In the video guide in the link you provided `xrdp` was set up on port 3390. `xrdp` should also have a log containing specifics of the error as well. Verify that your remote desktop is set up correctly and that your Kali Linux install in your WSL is set up correctly as well. Please edit your question to include these details. Thank you.

Comment: No the port that xrdp set up was 3390 same to what was in the video. I don't understand why it is connecting to 3350.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [bug](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1101) about this; apparently it happens because `xorgxrdp` is missing. Using the Xvnc backend as a workaround worked for me:

- Install `tigervnc`:

  ```
  # apt-get install tigervnc*
  ```
- When connecting to the remote desktop, choose "Xvnc" as the session type.